# WiX Installer does not add Application to Programs and Features

Tags: vb.net, wix

I have a VB.net based WiX installer which seems to function as required in that it copies all the relevent files to the target folders on the machine, however for some reason the installer does not appear to present the application in Programs and Features.  I am a relative newbie to WiX and based this WiX Installer project on a previous Windows Service project that I developed, which worked properly. Hoping someone can point out to me where I am going wrong.  Code detailed below, please note all registry entries and GUIDs have been hashed-out for security purposes:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?define SourceDir = "..\..\Bin\Debug" ?>
 <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"  xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
<Product Id="*" Name="PSALERTSClient" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Iberdrola, S.A." UpgradeCode="a6fd9179-efe6-47d1-bd8f-aec182d36c8b">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="PSALERTS Client" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpDirQuery" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpDirQueryOutput" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpQueryExe" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpQueryPdb" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpBusinessLogicDll" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpBusinessLogicPdb" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpBusinessObjectDll" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpBusinessObjectPdb" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpCommonDll" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpCommonPdb" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpDataAccessDll" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpDataAccessPdb" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpDPAPIHelperDll" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpDPAPIHelperPdb" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpLoggerDll" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpLoggerPdb" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpPSALERTSIni" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpPSALERTSXltm" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpPSALERTSUserGuideChm" />    
</Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="dirSPEnergyNetworks" Name="SP Energy Networks">
      <!-- <Component Id="cmpDirSPEnergyNetworks" Guid="{####################################}" Transitive="yes" /> -->
      <Directory Id="dirPSALERTS" Name="PSALERTS">
        <!-- <Component Id="cmpDirPSALERTS" Guid="{####################################}" Transitive="yes" /> -->
        <Directory Id="dirQuery" Name="Query">
          <Component Id="cmpDirQuery" Guid="{####################################}" KeyPath="yes">
            <CreateFolder Directory="dirQuery" />
            <RemoveFile Id="PurgeQuery" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" />
            <RemoveFolder Id="idDirQuery" On="uninstall" Directory="dirQuery" />
          </Component>
          <Directory Id="dirQueryOutput" Name="QueryOutput">
            <Component Id="cmpDirQueryOutput" Guid="{####################################}">
              <CreateFolder Directory="dirQueryOutput" />
              <RemoveFile Id="PurgeQueryOutput" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" />
              <RemoveFolder Id="idDirQueryOutputRemove" On="uninstall" Directory="dirQueryOutput" />
            </Component>
          </Directory>
          <Component Id="cmpQueryExe" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filQueryExe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Query.exe" />
            <RemoveRegistryKey Id="RemoveQueryRegKey" Root="HKLM" Key="####################################" Action="removeOnUninstall" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpQueryPdb" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filQueryPdb" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Query.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpBusinessLogicDll" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filBusinessLogicDll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\BusinessLogic.dll"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpBusinessLogicPdb" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filBusinessLogicPdb" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\BusinessLogic.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpBusinessObjectDll" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filBusinessObjectDll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\BusinessObject.dll" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpBusinessObjectPdb" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filBusinessObjectPdb" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\BusinessObject.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpCommonDll" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filCommonDll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Common.dll" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpCommonPdb" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filCommonPdb" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Common.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpDataAccessDll" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filDataAccessDll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\DataAccess.dll" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpDataAccessPdb" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filDataAccessPdb" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\DataAccess.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpDPAPIHelperDll" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filDPAPIHelperDll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\DPAPIHelper.dll" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpDPAPIHelperPdb" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filDPAPIHelperPdb" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\DPAPIHelper.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpLoggerDll" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filLoggerDll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Logger.dll" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpLoggerPdb" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filLoggerPdb" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Logger.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpPSALERTSIni" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filPSALERTSIni" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\PSALERTS.ini" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpPSALERTSXltm" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filPSALERTSXltm" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\PSALERTS.xltm" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpPSALERTSUserGuideChm" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filPSALERTSUserGuideChm" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\PSALERTSUserGuide.Chm" />
          </Component>
      </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT to 0. You can add the following line under your < Package ... > line.

```
    <Property Id="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT">0</Property>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367750(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The link says it prevents application from showing in Control Panel.

Comment: You mention I can '..add the following under your line...'.  Under which line? :-)

Comment: Stack overflow was removing the text, edit it to show. It should be anywhere under package.